# palindrome number using recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion, palindrome

I'm just trying to find a palindrome number using recursion in C. However I'm making a mistake and that mistake I don't know. Every time it's giving me the result 0.

Here's the source code:

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int pal(int num);

void main()
{
    int num=625,res=0;
    res=pal(num);
    printf("%d",res);
    getch();
}

int pal(int num)
{
    int ans=0,rem=0,index=0;
    index=log10(num);
    if(index==0)
    {
        return ;
    }

    index--;

    rem=num%10;
    ans=ans*10+rem;
   return pal(index--);   
}
```

Please gimme the easiest way to find it. I need an easy to understand program.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. The code, that you provided [doesn't compile](https://ideone.com/7vZx1d).

Comment: What do you mean "find palindrome number"? How would that work for `625`? Would it be an error or should it print something like `62526`?

Comment: Your code has various non-standard things that make it hard for other people to compile it, perhaps you are using a very old or poor quality compiler? A few things to fix: Remove `#include <conio.h>` and `getch()`. Include `<math.h>` for the `log10` function. Make sure you return a value in the `if` block at the top of the `pal` function.

Comment: Once you have fixed those things, it would also help if you clearly explain the behaviour you want from your program. Given that your program clearly doesn't do what you wanted it to, it is hard for us to guess what you actually wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of problems:

- You're recursively calling `pal` with `index` instead of `num`;
- If `index` is 0, you need to return a value - what should that value be?
- `main` returns `int`, not `void`;
- Your description of what you want your code to do isn't clear - are you trying to reverse a number, determine whether it's palindromic, what?

Assuming you're trying to reverse a number, a recursive algorithm would look something like:

```
int reverse( int num )
{
  /**
   * Account for negative inputs by preserving the sign and 
   * converting the input to positive for processing.
   */
  int sign = 1;
  if ( num < 0 )
  {
    sign = -1;
    num = -num;
  }

  /**
   * If the input is a single digit, then there's
   * nothing to reverse and we return the original
   * input value.
   */
  if ( num < 10 )
    return sign * num;

  /**
   * Otherwise, find and preserve the least significant digit.
   */
  int remainder = num % 10; 

  /**
   * Recursively call reverse on the higher-order digits.
   */
  int rev = reverse( num / 10 ); 

  /**
   * Determine the order of magnitude of the reversed
   * value, multiply the remainder by that magnitude
   * to make it the new most significant digit.
   */
  for ( int tmp = rev; tmp; tmp /= 10 )
    remainder *= 10;

  /**
   * PARENTHESES MATTER HERE
   */
  return sign * (remainder + rev);
}
```

**EDIT**

I've added some documentation to hopefully make that code a little more clear.  I also changed the way I multiply `remainder` so it doesn't rely on the `pow` function.

Answer (score 4):

What exactly are you trying to do?

1.Checking if a number is palindrome.

2.Finding the next smallest/greater palindrome.

3.Finding the reverse of a number.

Note: A palindrome number is a number that reads the same from both ends.

For example:

```
         12321 -> palindrome number
         23143 -> not palindrome number
         7     -> palindrome number
```

To check if a number is palindrome or not first find the reverse of that number if reverse is equal to that number then that number is palindrome else not.

Answer (score 4):

```
int pal(int num){
  int n=0;
  while (num != 0){
    n = n * 10;
    n = n + num%10;
    num = num/10;
  }
  return num;
}
```

This function will return you a reversed number which you can compare with the input and `if(input == pal(input))` then it is a pallidrome other wise it is not. Hope it will help you.

Comment: OP is trying to use recursion.

Comment: I know @FiddlingBits, but he asked for the easiest way to find and which is understandable.

Answer (score 3):

Completely reversing a number to check it against the original seems the wrong way to test if a number is a palindrome. Once digits on the left and right end of the number don't match, you're done, you don't need to continue reversing the number.  The solution is in the process, not in the result.

Here's a simple recursive palindrome number predicate function:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_palindrome(unsigned long long number)
{
    unsigned int logarithm = log10(number);

    if (logarithm == 0)
    {
        return true;  // single digit numbers are palindromes
    }

    unsigned long long power = pow(10, logarithm);

    unsigned int left = number / power;
    unsigned int right = number % 10;

    if (left == right)
    {
        // ends match, so toss 'em and test what's left recursively
        return is_palindrome((number - left * power) / 10);
    }

    return false;  // ends don't match, so not a palindrome
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    printf("%s\n", is_palindrome(atoll(argv[1])) ? "Yes" : "No");

    return 1;
}
```

**TEST CASES**

```
% ./a.out 6
Yes
% ./a.out 66
Yes
% ./a.out 666
Yes
% ./a.out 625
No
% ./a.out 12345678987654321
Yes
% ./a.out 31415
No
```